# highstock. Don't update navigator series visibility

Tags: legend, highcharts

i'm having some troubles solving this.
I need to keep navigator series always visible.
The problem is when i click in one legend item, the serie linked to this legend dissappears. Thats fine.
But the serie in the navigator dissappears to, and i don't want this.

I tried with the "adaptToUpdatedData" parameter, not working.

I tried handling the events in "legendItemClick" and hide show the series manually, but this hides the navigator series also.

Please help! I tried almost everything.

The only i managed to achieve it is keeping all the series with the parameter "showInNavigator" false, and then add the series in navigator.series.

But i think is not a good solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I add `hide` events to series with `showInNavigator: true`. These call a function which does:

```
var chart = this.$refs.highcharts.chart
for (var series of chart.navigator.series) {
    series.setVisible(true, false)
}
chart.redraw()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Highcharts `removeEvent` method to remove the connection when changing visibility between the chart series and the navigator series:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load() {
            this.series.forEach(function(s) {
                if (!s.baseSeries) {
                    H.removeEvent(s, 'show');
                    H.removeEvent(s, 'hide');
                }
            });
        }
    }
},
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/69rwjsce/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.removeEvent%3CT%3E